# Making activity fullscreen in Android 4.0

Tags: fullscreen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've looked for it in many web sites. I wanna make my activity full screen in Android 4.0 (Whole screen with even virtual buttons and bar). There are many solutions even in Stack Overflow. Many of them are ticked as it works. However when I try these solutions, they don't work! I couldn't find where I am making the mistake. I'm giving an example code that was given as answer for my problem (it's worked as they said):

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class ActivityName extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't enough:

```cs
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

In order to accomplish what you want to accomplish, add this:

```cs
this.getWindow().getDecorView()
        .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

I know this is a rather old question (with a bunch of duplicates), but this is found via Google so I figured I'd still post this solution.